# Consumer with comment permission

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I m using alfresco community 5.0 and i want to add the permission of adding comments to the consumer.

To do this, i add a group permission called createcomments to the permissions definition file which is associated to the permissions called createcomment and i modified the comments-list.js file so it uses the createcomment permissions.
After this modifications, all the users couldn't comment.

Here is what i modified in comments-list.js file

```
 handlePermissions: function CommentsList_handlePermissions(oRequest, oFullResponse)
  {
     // Examine the user permissions on the parent node
     var permissions = oFullResponse.nodePermissions || {};
     if (permissions["CreateComments"])
     {
        Dom.removeClass(this.id + "-actions", "hidden");
     }
     else
     {
        Dom.addClass(this.id + "-actions", "hidden");
     }

     // Return response unmodified
     return oFullResponse;
  },
```

Any hint or suggestions would be very appreciated.

Comment: Please refer this https://community.alfresco.com/thread/200805-consumer-can-add-comments. may  you will get some idea.

Comment: thanks for your comment i followed exactly the steps in that discussion but it doesn't work , i don't know how to expose the permission to the documentlibrary.

Comment: did you see in permission list , see my answer in this post [Manage Permission](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40973396/how-to-manage-access-permission-in-alfresco/41011753#41011753), search for something like can comment action

Comment: there is no permission accorded to comments, it is included with the addChildren permissions so if we give the addchildren permission to the consumer, he will also be able to upload files.