# How to Deny delete access to document owner in Alfresco 5.0

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

In my application user is having collaborator permission, and he is uploading document in site.

But by default he is getting Delete document access.

So i want to remove that delete access from 3 places, that is from doclib action and also from multi select option.

Does anyone did this before?

Please reply.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Hi All, is there any other way.. Please reply

Comment: Please see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38713784/how-to-get-acls-of-a-document/38721064#38721064

Comment: you can also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40973396/how-to-manage-access-permission-in-alfresco/41011753#41011753

Answer (score 4):

You need to understand the owner concept of alfresco. The owner has all permissions on a node similar to the coordinator. If the owner is not explicitly set alfresco assumes the creator as owner.
Changing the collaborator role is the wrong track since this role does not have the remove permission. So to remove the delete (remove) permission you need to set the owner to system or admin by something like a rule or a behaviour. You could write a simple javascript which sets the owner to 'system' and set this script to be executed in all new elements in a folder hierarchy.
Be careful when using CIFS or WebDav: Most applications don't support this use case. apps like office or creative suite don't write once on save and will fail if they can't delete a document they just created. Same thing with temp files. To work around this pitfall you can use "Online Edit" (Sharepoint protocol from the Share UI) instead but this is limited to MS Office only. If you need a solution for other Apps: Send me a PM. We have a OS independent agent which could do the same for any document type.

Comment: I am agree with you, but in my case we are creating site through bootstrap, and everything is automated. So we don't want to do anything manually. in above case we need to write script and need to set rule manually.   So i am preferring to override permissiondefination.xml

Comment: Can you give me some more idea about permissiondefination.xml

Comment: Even if you have a fully automated scenario: you need to remove the owner to disallow the creator to have full access. It is no solution to change the owner role since this will result in an unusable alfresco and as said: the collaborator doesn't have the delete permission. 
There are several ways to to remove/set the owner during bootstrap: Write a policy, run a batch directly after you created the stuff, set owner 'system' in your bootstrap data, ...

Answer (score 2):

```
You can do this 2 ways.
1)you can override permissiondefination.xml and remove delete permission from collaborator.
2)another way is you can define rule on folder and execute script, where in script write logic to remove permission on node for collaborator.
```

Comment: i will choose first way, so can you please provide sample code to override permissiondefinition.xml file....

Comment: one another  and easy to achieve this is change owner of upload document using rule.

Comment: If possible, please provide the sample code to override permissiondefinition.xml file.   It will be more suitable for me...

Comment: actually we can not remove permission from owner of the document using permissiondefinition.xml,just try another option

Comment: Actually i don't want to remove permission.  If i will be able to remove  only delete access then also its Ok...

Comment: please refer http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/references/API-JS-removePermission.html . i am not sure about that we can remove permission from owner of document.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132908/discussion-between-sanjay-patel-and-deepak-talape).

Comment: Better way to change the owner of document.